# PHP change multidimensional array index in running foreach

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, indexing, foreach

I am trying to change multidimensional array index in running foreach:

```
$array = array(
    array("apple", "orange"),
    array("carrot", "potato")
    );

$counter = 0;

foreach($array[$counter] as &$item) {
    echo $item . " - ";
    $counter = 1;
}
```

I supposed, that output would be ***apple - carrot - potato -***, because in first run it takes value from zero array and then in next runs values from first array.

However, the output is ***apple - orange -***

I tried add "&" before variable $item, but i guess it is not what I am looking for.

Is there any way to do it?
Thank you

// Well, i will try to make it cleaner:
This foreach takes values from $array[0], but in run i want to change index to 1, so in next repeat it will take values from $array[1]

Is that clear enough?

**Note:** I do not know how many dimensions my array has.

My purpose of this is not to solve this exact case, all I need to know is if is it possible to change source of foreach loop in run:

My foreach

```
$counter = 0;
foreach($array[$counter] as $item) {
 echo $item . " - ";
}
```

is getting values from $array[0] right now. But inside it, I want to change $counter to 1, so next time it repeats, it will get values from $array[1]

```
$counter = 0;
foreach($array[$counter] as $item) {
 echo $item . " - ";
 $counter = 1;
}
```

I see, it is kind of hard to explain. This is how foreach should work:
*Index of $array is $counter*

**First run**
$array[0] -> as $item = apple
echo apple
wait, now counter changes to 1

**Second run**
$array[1] -> as $item = carrot
echo carrot

**Third run**
$array[1] -> as $item = potato
echo potato

**END**

I am really trying to make it clear as much as possible :D

Comment: Pretty Unclear what you want to achieve over here.

Comment: foreach loop gets variable $array[0] and works on it

Comment: Do you want `apple-carrot-potato` or `apple-orrange-carrot-potato` ?

Comment: I want apple-carrot-potato, because in the moment when i change index to 1, next repeat should get values from $array[1], if is that even possible.

Comment: 1st of all you are missing quotation marks in your seconds array elements. If that an array with 2 elements in your posted code.

Comment: Damn i deleted someone´s answer, sorry, that was not my purpose :D
I wanted to respond, that  i do not know how many dimensions my array has, so i need to change target of getting values.

Yeah this is just example code, it does not matter, but thanks, i will fix it.

Comment: How about this `echo $array[0][0];
foreach($array[1] as $item) {
 echo " - ".$item;
}`

Comment: Well, i dont have a static array, it changes, so i do not know how many dimensions it has. 
The code above is just an example, so i can not do it this way.  
All I need to know, is if is it possible to change source of foreach loop in run. (From $array[0] to $array[1])

Comment: but you want only one (first) item from first array, and ?? all items from next array/arrays?

Comment: In this example, yes. But my purpose is not to solve this example, but to find out, if is possible to do a thing i am talking about whole time :D

Comment: what you want do you want to remove every subarray's first index?

Comment: this is your code plus an echo of the counter, `$counter = 0;
foreach($array[$counter] as &$item) {
 echo ' '.$counter." - ".$item;
 $counter = 1;
}`

Comment: maybe give some more examples :)

Comment: I edited my original post, hope you get it :D

Comment: you wrote that you didn't know how many dimensions it has, so what if array look like that `$array = array(
    array("apple", "orange"),
    array("carrot", "potato"),
    array("raspberry", "cherry")
    );`

Comment: from ssnake array your desire output will be apple-carrot-potato-raspberry ? Do you want this type of dynamic output? Here orange and cherry excluded from array.

Comment: No, i do not. If i set $counter to 1 after outputing first  value from $arrray[0], it should output all values from $array[1] and then end. Just if i set variable $counter to 2 somewhere, then it should continue from $array[2]. Ah it is complicated.

Comment: but for now you want first element from first array and all from secend? `echo $array[0][0] . " - " . implode(" - ", $array[1]);` [example](https://eval.in/565974)

Comment: Yeeeah but i do not want solve this example because its just an example. My code is much more complicated and everything I want is to change foreach source array index during loop. Maybe when I come home I will show you full code.

Comment: `foreach` gets array as value. As Shady wrote, you cannot change the iteration index of `foreach` as the pointer to that is still pointing to the previous result. doing so won't change the pointer and continue as it is. you nee to use for or while loop, maybe recursion depending on your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When foreach first starts executing, the internal array pointer is automatically reset to the first element of the array. Now, by changing counter, you are changing the array (the inside one), but it is set to the first array again.

Changing the array in between may result in unexpected behaviour.

Source: [Foreach: PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: Well, that is good to know. Hmm. Could I do it by for loop then? Thanks

Comment: for($c=0; $c<2;$c++) {
  $item = $array[$c][0];
  echo $item . " - ";
  
}

With the above code, source is changed using For loop, Just tweaking it a little with one extra counter will also solve the actual example you gave @Mamut

Comment: Of course, but can i change variable $c inside the loop? Like in my example above

Comment: `$array = array(
    array("apple", "orange"),
    array("carrot", "potato"),
    array("mango", "doesn't matter"),
    array("grapes", "doesn't matter"),
    );
$counter = 0;
for($c=0; $c<4;$c++) {
  $item = $array[$c][0];
  $c++; 
  echo $item . " - ";
  echo " ";  
}`

Sure you can

Comment: I did not even realize, there is for loop too :D this is not final version how it should work, but I will try something and i will come back then with solution or with another question :D

Answer (score 0):

So finally, I found a time for this, and this is how you can change index of source array in running loop.

Thanks to you, I realized, that i can not do this by foreach, but there are many other loops.

If you were facing the same problem, here is my solution:

```
$array = array(
 array("apple", "orange"),
 array("carrot", "potato")
);

$counter = 0;
$x = 0;

while($x < count($array[$counter])) {
    echo $array[$counter][$x] . " - ";
    $x++;
    if($counter == 0) {
        $x = 0;
        $counter = 1;
    }
}
```

And the output is: **apple - carrot - potato -** as I wanted to achieve.